# Is there a builtin function version of `and` and/or `or` in Python?

Tags: python

This question is for fun; I don't expect the answer to be useful.

When I see people doing things with `reduce()` in Python, they often take advantage of a builtin function in Python, often from the `operator` module.

This works:

```
result = reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, range(5))
```

But usually you would see this:

```
from operator import add
result = reduce(add, range(5))
```

What's strange to me is that the `operator` module doesn't seem to have a function for logical `and`.  It does have *bitwise* and, but not logical `and`.

So suppose you are doing this:

```
result = reduce(lambda a, b: a and b, range(1, 6))
```

Is there a builtin function that can be used here?

I'm also wondering if there is a builtin function that can replace `or`.

If you map the arguments to Booleans first, you can use the bitwise and from `operator`, or just directly use `bool.__and__`, like so:

```
from operator import and_
result = reduce(and_, map(bool, range(1, 6)))
result = reduce(bool.__and__, map(bool, range(1, 6)))
```

And likewise with `operator.or_()` or `bool.__or__` for the `or` operation.  But I am looking for a function that doesn't need the values mapped to Booleans.

If you knew for certain that your values are all integers, you could use `operator.mul` for `and` and `operator.add` for `or`.  This would be a crude hack and I don't want this answer... especially considering how expensive the multiplications would get if many numbers were encountered and none of them were zero!

Note: I am aware of `all()` and `any()`, which are better replacements for this use of `reduce()`.  As I said at the top, I'm asking this for fun.

Note: A function that has the side-effect of forcing all values to `bool` would be an acceptable answer.  The built-in `and` keyword doesn't do this:

```
x = 3 and 5  # sets x to 5, not to True
```

But for the purpose of this question I am just interested in a function that can work with `reduce()` to do logical `and` or `or` operations.

Comment: You could use `any((a, b))` for `a or b` and `all((a, b))` for `a and b`. Of course, then you've got to make the tuples, and there's no short-circuiting...

Comment: `x = 3 and 5` sets `x` to `5` but you can cast it to a boolean too, so why not use that? The point is that whatever logical expression you try to evaluate `x` in, it will be interpreted as a boolean.

Comment: @steveha nice question. I hope you get an answer but it seems like you've gone through every alternative already in your answer

Comment: Im just wondering why this isn't in the `operator` module

Comment: @jamylak maybe someone should propose adding `both` and `either` to the `operator` module, to be the logical counterparts of the bitwise `and_` and `or_`.

Comment: @MarkRansom: See thg435's answer for why they don't exist

Comment: @NeilG, just because the operators short circuit doesn't mean it would be a requirement for an equivalent function. My proposal above uses different names which should reduce the possibility of confusion.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Why not just pass a pair to `any` or `all`?

Comment: Another option is to just make `any` and `all` have a two-parameter version that does what you want, just like `max` and `min`?

Comment: @NeilG, is there a function factory that wraps a function and two parameters to produce a function and a tuple? If so, that would make an answer to the question. I like your suggestion of having `any` and `all` take multiple parameters, no reason they couldn't work like `min` and `max`.

Comment: Since `max()` and `min()` both work with multiple parameters, maybe Python could have `any()` and `all()` do the same.  That would make a very tidy answer to this question! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the actual reason why there's no `and` and `or` in the operator module is that it's impossible to evaluate function arguments in a short-circuit fashion - which is the whole point of boolean operators. So the answer to your question is no, there's no built-in function that can mimic `and/or` nor is it possible to write one.

`all/any` applied to generators are short-circuiting as well

```
def gen():
    yield 1
    yield this_wont_be_evaluated

print any(gen())
```

but I have no idea how make that work with run-time arguments

Comment: I thought short circuiting was simply a useful property of logical operators, not "the whole point".

Comment: This is exactly the answer to the question asked: There are no `and` and `or` functions in the operator module because you cannot define these functions. Having functions that are close, but not the same would simply be misleading.

Comment: I agree that it's impossible to evaluate function arguments in short-circuit fashion.  However, if you want short-circuit behavior, you should be using `all()` or `any()` rather than `reduce()`.  I still would like to see a logical-and function in `operator`, although I admit the `lambda` is trivial to write.

Comment: How is short-circuiting "the point" of `and` and `or`, let alone "the whole point"? The point is to evaluate a boolean expressions. Short-circuiting is an additional feature that saves unnecessary function evaluation, which could also be implemented with regular operators (think `def __and(x, y): if x == False: return False [..]`). I don't see any point at all to not making them regular operators. And @JochenRitzel What do you mean? Of course you can define those functions. The OP did it, as did I in my answer. And they are exactly the same, only they can be used as functional arguments.

Comment: @StjepanBakrac: note that your example is NOT short-circuiting: it evaluates both `x` and `y`.

Comment: You're right, sorry about that. It wouldn't work without some form of lazy evaluation.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer, because I don't think any better one is going to appear and this one was first.  But I still don't agree that short-circuit evaluation is "the whole point" of a logical `and` or logical `or` function.

Answer (score 1):

There are no builtin functions I'm aware of that do this. However, you can define trivial functions that wrap around the operators:

```
>>> def newand(a,b):
...  return a and b
...
>>> def newor(a,b):
...  return a or b
...
>>> reduce(newand, map(bool, range(5))) # Will return False, because bool(0) == False
False
>>> reduce(newand, map(bool, range(1,5))) # Now 0 is excluded
True
```

Comment: This is the same as the `lambda`, it's not a builtin function as asked

Comment: That has been answered as well, though, both in my answer and others, namely that those doesn't exist. Which kinda bugs me as well, because I feel they should be part of it. Sadly, Python isn't perfect and this is all we can do about it since `and`, `or` and `not` are special conditional constructs, closer to `if` than the regular operators (which is also why you can't overload them, another sad fact).

Comment: @StjepanBakrac: Why would you want to overload `and` or `or` in any way that disagrees with `__bool__`?

Comment: Because sometimes you work with data structures that don't have a unique `True` or `False` representation, but can still be compared in a logical way to others. I had that problem recently with database queries. I ended up overloading `&` and `|` instead, but it's not the same, because their precedence is different. You can't do `a == b & c == d`, because it'll scope `a == (b & c) == d`, unlike `a == b and c == d`, which would be `(a == b) and (c == d)`. That means, you end up with one extra level of nesting parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: A function that has the side-effect of forcing all values to
>   bool would be an acceptable answer. The built-in and keyword doesn't
>   do this

but the built-in `not` keyword does.

```
In : not 255
Out: False

In : not 0
Out: True
```

of course, you'll have to get your logic backwards, then:

```
In : not (not 5 and not 0) # mimics: 5 or 0
Out: True
```

so, with this you can emulate `all()` via `reduce`, `map`, and `operator.*`:

```
In : not reduce(operator.or_,map(operator.not_,[1,2,3,4,5])) # mimics all(1,2,3,4,5)
Out: True

In : not reduce(operator.or_,map(operator.not_,[1,2,3,0,5])) # mimics all(1,2,3,0,5)
Out: False
```

is that (sort of) what you wanted to achieve? I'm afraid we cannot get any closer.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see how I could use any of the above in a `reduce()` statement.  I need a callable, and if I need to write a `lambda` to wrap up some code I would just write the `lambda` that invokes `and` or `or` on its arguments.

Comment: You suggest using `not` to map values to Booleans, but you note that we would then need to invert the logic.  I suggest it would be simpler to use `bool()` to map values to Booleans, because then we wouldn't need to invert the logic.  See the original question for an example of this, starting at the text "If you map the arguments to Booleans first".