# Why don't any and all take multiple parameters like min and max?

Tags: python, parameters, language-design

The functions `min` and `max` are very flexible; they can take any number of parameters, or a single parameter that is an iterable. `any` and `all` are similar in taking an iterable of any size, but they do not take more than one parameter. Is there a reason for this difference in behavior?

I realize that the question might seem unanswerable, but the process of enhancing Python is pretty open; many seemingly arbitrary design decisions are part of the public record. I've seen similar questions answered in the past, and I'm hoping this one can be as well.

Inspired by this question: [Is there a builtin function version of `and` and/or `or` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959500/is-there-a-builtin-function-version-of-and-and-or-or-in-python)

Comment: When I think of universal quantifiers such as `any` and `all`, I don't really expect to do any filtering on them upon quantification.  Same applies here - why would I want to filter on [whatever] if I'm interested in either one element or all elements being true?

Comment: I guess a case like `all([0, 0], 1)` would be kinda confusing.  Then again, `max([0, 0], 1)` is not much better ....

Comment: @wim, `min([0, 0], 1)` doesn't work the way you expect either. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @wim That's not a good point because that has been dealt with in Python 3

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the features in Python are suggested based on how much users need them, however they must also conform to the style of the language. People often need to do this:

```
max_val = 0
for x in seq:
    # ... do complex calculations
    max_val = max(max_val, result)
```

which warrants the use of the multiple parameters. It also looks good. I haven't heard of anyone needing to use `any(x, y, z)` because it is most often used on sequences. For a small number of values you can just use the `and`/`or` logical operators and for a lot of values you really should be using a list anyway or your code gets messy. I'm certain that not much thought has gone into this because it really wouldn't benefit anyone, it hasn't been under large demand so the Python devs don't worry about it.

Comment: I agree about conforming to the style of the language, but I think that having a precedent in a similar function would be the style to emulate. Arbitrary differences always cause confusion.

Comment: @MarkRansom If we add that feature do people still do `x and y and z` or should they use `all(x, y, z)`? I think it would create more confusion. `and` works better too as we have already discussed in that other thread

Comment: That's a different thing entirely.  `and` must return one of the operands, whereas `all` will return bool

Comment: @wim True, I was talking about in an `if` statement though I should have mentioned that, bad example anyway.

Comment: I know that Python prefers to have one obvious way to do things, and `and` and `or` will always be that way. It's just a matter of having an alternate when those won't work.